# Call a function before class constructor

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make classes to program easier with sdl2 in c++, the thing is when I initialize my class Engine, I want to call `SDL_Init` before initializing private members because my `Window`, `Renderer` and `Texture` can't have default constructors, and I don't want to initialize them 2 times. How could I do that ? (Sorry if this is not very clear, I'm french)

```
Engine::Engine(bool windowed, std::uint32_t flags, std::uint32_t format,
    std::uint32_t rendererFlags, std::uint32_t textureAccess) /* I want to initialize my window, etc.. here */ {
    if (SDL_Init(flags))
        throw (std::runtime_error(SDL_GetError()));
    _window = Window(ENGINE_WINDOW_WIDTH, ENGINE_WINDOW_HEIGHT, windowed);
    _renderer = Renderer(_window, rendererFlags);
    _windowTexture = Texture(_renderer, ENGINE_WINDOW_WIDTH,
        ENGINE_WINDOW_HEIGHT, format, textureAccess);
}
```

Comment: You can create a wrapper for your Engine. So the user ultimately provokes the wrapper class while the wrapper initialise the engine and passes the window objects

Comment: Thanks, good idea, don't know why i didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood well, what I need to do is create a wrapper class like this:

```
class EngineWrapper {
    public:
    inline EngineWrapper(std::uint32_t flags) {
        SDL_Init(flags);
    }
}
```

and then make my Engine inherit from that class like this

```
class Engine : public EngineWrapper { ... }
```

I'm not really sure that this was what @Nina meant but this should do the job

Comment: That's one way, the other way is to make them two completely separate classes where there is no inheritence and the EngineWrapper constructor creates the window and initialises the Engine class instance and keeps the instance as a variable then passes the window objects to it

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, I prefer this design thought, It doesn't change any of my code as the constructor of EngineWrapper is called automatically before Engine's constructor

Comment: Sure if that works for you then it's completely fine.